# Change Date Format ui:inputDateTime lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I need to change the format that the selected date displays in, for the ui:inputDateTime .
[image]

I want it to display in the format "MM/dd/yyyy"

the tag looks like this :

```
<ui:inputDateTime aura:id="EndDateField" value="{!v.Task.pse__End_Date_Time__c }" displayDatePicker="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update** looks like it is a bug in the date/time input

Seems that the DateTime does not utilize the format and uses the locale?

If you do not need the time then this does format properly

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="EndDateField" value="{!v.Task.pse__End_Date_Time__c }" displayDatePicker="true" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
```

**original discussion**

Add the `format="MM/dd/yyyy"`

```
<ui:inputDateTime aura:id="EndDateField" value="{!v.Task.pse__End_Date_Time__c }" displayDatePicker="true" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDateTime.htm

> format | String | The java.text.SimpleDateFormat style format string.

Comment: It is working Just try this: `<ui:inputDate aura:id="expiry-date" class="field" value="{!v.today}" displayDatePicker="true" format="MM/DD/YYYY" />` The only thing missing in the above answer is a double quote...

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that Salesforce has listed as "No Fix" https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000AU8aQAG

[image: nofix]