# ui:inputDate how to show month number and not month string

Tags: lightning, string, number, format, ui-inputdate

My problem is that I'm not able to get the date with a month number format.

This is my code:

```
    <ui:inputDate aura:id="input" 
        value="2018-01-01"
        format="dd-MM-yyyy"
        displayDatePicker="true"
        disabled="true"
        required="true" />
```

As we can see, the input is disabled by default, so if we enable the inputDate again we'll see that the month is showing as string and not as a number, here is an example:

[image]

How could I force the ui component to show month as a number? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CNVQA2

Comment: Also, this might be relevant: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163257/change-date-format-uiinputdatetime-lightning-component

Comment: I've edited the problem description so you can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made up a quick solution, but I think it should be a better solution.
This is my code:

```
    <aura:if isTrue="{!(!v.disabled)}">
        <ui:inputDate aura:id="input" 
            value="{!v.date}"
            format="dd/MM/yyyy"
            displayDatePicker="true"
            required="{!v.required}" />
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <ui:inputDate aura:id="input" displayDatePicker="true" disabled="{!v.disabled}"/>
    </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
```

This causes the disabled input to be destroyed, when the disabled status change, and a new one is rendered without being disabled by default and, thus, with the desired format.