# ui:inputDateTime does not respect format

Tags: lightning, ui, ui-inputdate

I'm dynamically creating a ui:inputDateTime component -- however it does not accept the format that I specified

```
{
            "aura:id":"selectDateTime",
            "format":"MM/dd/yyyy HH-mm-ss z",
            "class":"field",
            "displayDatePicker":"true"
},
```

instead it presents date in this format: "May 3rd, 2018 .. any work around for this or understanding why?

Comment: Are you using a tablet or phone? `Web apps running on mobiles and tablets use an input field of type datetime for all browsers except Internet Explorer. The value is displayed based on the locale of the browser, for example, MMM d, yyyy and h:mm:ss a, which is returned by $Locale.dateFormat and $Locale.timeFormat.`

Comment: This answer may have what you need if you don't need time component: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163257/change-date-format-uiinputdatetime-lightning-component

Comment: nope, just running on chrome/safari for desktop -- and yeah i actually need the time component too :/